# Loading the PNG Image by webgl is not perfect

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

When using the `canvas.getContext('2d')` to load the png file which has a transparent part, it looks exactly the same as the png file itself. But when loading by `canvas.getContext('webgl')`, it will display as white in the transparent part. And then if you add `discard` in the shader, it will be better but still not perfect as the png file. How to fix this issue?

---

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, this.img);
```

---

```
void main() {
      vec4 color = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);
      if(color.a < 0.5) {
         discard;
      }
      gl_FragColor = color;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transparency is actually kind of complicated

There is

## #1 what the canvas itself needs

The default canvas wants premultiplied alpha. In other words it wants you to provide RGBA values where RGB has been multiplied by A.

You can set the canvas so it does not expect premultiplied alpha when creating the webgl context by passing in `premultipledAlpha: false` as in

```
const gl = someCanvas.getContext('webgl', {premultipliedAlpha: false});
```

Note: IIRC This doesn't work on iOS.

### #2 what format you load the images

The default for loading images in WebGL is unpremultiplied alpha. In other words if the image has a pixel that is

```
255, 128, 64, 128   RGBA
```

It will be loaded exactly like that (*)

You can tell WebGL to premultiply for you when loading an image by setting

```
gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, true);
```

Before calling `gl.texImage2D`.

Now that same pixel will above will end up being

```
128, 64, 16, 128    RGBA
```

Each of RGB has been multiplied by A (A above is 128 where 128 represents 128/255 or 0.5019607843137255)

## #3 what you write out in your shaders

If you loaded un-premultiplied data you might choose to premultiply in your shader

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(someColor.rgb * someColor.a, someColor.a);
```

## #4 how you blend

If you want to blend what you are drawing into what has already been drawn then you need to turn on blending

```
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
```

But you also need to set how the blending happens. There are multiple functions that affect blending. The most common one to use is `gl.blendFunc` which sets how the src pixel (the one generated by your shader) and the dst pixel (the one being drawn on top of in the canvas) are affected before being combined. The 2 most common settings are

```
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);  // unpremultiplied alpha
```

and

```
gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);  // premultiplied alpha
```

The first argument is how to multiply the src pixel. Above we are either multiplying by the alpha of the src (SRC_ALPHA) or by 1 (ONE). The second argument is how to multiply the dst pixel. ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA is exactly what it says (1 - alpha)

How you put all these together is up to you.

[This article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-and-alpha.html) and [This one](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-text-texture.html) somewhat cover these issues

(*) Images may have [color conversion applied](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#PIXEL_STORAGE_PARAMETERS).

Comment: Many thanks! I have tried out all 4 suggestions listed above. The #4 blend function works as expected with the first common setting. Compared with canvas2d, however, the PNG file rendered by webgl is not as smooth as it rendered by canvas2d in detail. Is there any other setting could be used to make it exactly the same as canvas2d performs?

Comment: FYI, the first setting is wrong for standard canvas. See #1   In any case you need to post code I think (better in a new question).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may need to activate blending.

```
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
```

And then set the blending function to work with pre-multiplied alpha (the default)

```
gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, yes I enable the blending now. But I choose gl.SRC_ALPHA as the first argument as gl.ONE will change the transparent pixels in white.